# On firebase UI authentication example getting: Uncaught FirebaseError: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am following the example of the [firebase UI repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) but I get the following error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).

I've tried already several things, but they don't work. When I inspect the code it seems that it runs first the line containing `var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());` before `const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` even if it is afterwards.

This is my code, help will be welcomed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: "<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>",
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
        // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
        // function.
        // Terms of service url/callback.
        tosUrl: "<your-tos-url>",
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
          window.location.assign("<your-privacy-policy-url>");
        },
      };

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
         Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorder the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
   
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
         Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: "<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>",
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
        // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
        // function.
        // Terms of service url/callback.
        tosUrl: "<your-tos-url>",
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
          window.location.assign("<your-privacy-policy-url>");
        },
      };


      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(app.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You are using Firebase Compatibility Mode (the new API is different now, https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

You should put your code before </body> tag, so when the DOM is ready the scripts outside a function are loaded (http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_whereto.html)

Note that you are exposing the Firebase config if you put it inline, you should adopt another strategy [https://medium.com/@devesu/how-to-secure-your-firebase-project-even-when-your- api -key-is-publicly-available-a462a2a58843](https://medium.com/@devesu/how-to-secure-your-firebase-project-even-when-your-api-key-is-publicly-available-a462a2a58843). There are several strategies you can adopt.

Comment: That was an awesome answer and it worked! THANKS Mauro!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using compat SDKs, initialize Firebase SDK as shown below:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Comment: This didn't work  by itself but was part of the problem. Thanks anyway!